# Rendering a video being streamed by VLC in Virtual Reality in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, streaming, virtual-reality

I am trying to stream a video (*.mp4 format*) from VLC Media Player to Unity in virtual reality using HTTP. The video player source is **not** local file. Instead a local file is being streamed (using Stream utility of VLC player) in VLC using http and I want the source to be URL and I provide the URL to video player like: "**http://my_ip:8080/**".

When I test this stream on a new instance of VLC using Network Stream, everything seems to be working fine. Also, when I render the video from a local file source onto Unity, no issue in rendering.

However, only when I provide URL of the video source, the video is not rendered. I understand that RTSP and RTP protocols don't work but the Unity documentation says that HTTP works in Unity Video Player URL.

I don't understand why then the video is not being rendered.

Comment: **(1)** Have you ever loaded a video into Unity using HTTP request? If no, then forget about VLC and virtual reality and focus on loading a [simple MP4](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) from the web. If you cannot play it (after setting URL in Assets) then your **real question** is not about VLC... **(2)** What happens if you start transmitting your VLC stream **after** the Unity app started running? It's possible from Unity side that you are missing the first transmitted VLC stream packet (if you miss the first keyframe, you won't get a picture)..